# Limits of weighted sum vs weighted sum squared

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequence of $a_{i,t}, b_{i,t} > 0$ such that for all $t$

1. $B/2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^k b^2_{i,t} \leq B$ for some constant $B>0$,
2. $1/t \leq a_{i,t} \leq 1$

Is it possible that the weighted sum is lower bounded by some constant $C$: $\lim_{t\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{t}^{m(t)} a_{i,t} b_{i,t} \geq C$ while the sum squared limit goes to zero i.e.
$\lim_{t\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{t}^{m(t)} a_{i,t} b^2_{i,t} \to 0$?

Here $m: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with $m(t)> t$. Couple of notes:

1. If $a_{i,t} = a_{j,t}$ for all $i, j \in [k]$, then it's not possible.
2. If $b_{i,t}$ were not lower bounded then $b_{i,t} = 1/t$ would make it possible.